# Error compiling OpenSSL with MinGW/MSYS

Tags: makefile, openssl, mingw, msys

Download source files from [official OpenSSL site](http://www.openssl.org/source/). I follow the INSTALL.M32 file in OpenSSL folder. I open msys.bat, go to the OpenSSL folder, then type

```
$ ./config
```

It says "Configured for MinGW", than I type

```
$ make
```

and after few minutes receive error:

```
md2test.c:1:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the problem was that few test files (3 as far as I remember) had instead of C++-code the name of file (something like dummitest.c). I copy-paste the right code to that files from files from other folder, but with the same name, and everything went fine.

Comment: This sounds exactly like a problem with symbolic links. The other affected files are `rc5test.c` and `jpaketest.c`.

Answer (score 15):

I simply opened the files that were causing the error (/test/"md5test.c; rc5test.c; jpaketest.c") and replaced the line

```
dummytest.c
```

to

```
#include "dummytest.c"
```

It's the same solution as stated above, except it's a bit faster...

Comment: typo: /test/"md2test.c with a 2 instead of a 5   +1

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that `md2test.c` is actually a **symbolic link**, or **symlink** to `dummytest.c`.

If you extracted `openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz` with anything other than

```
tar xf openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
```

then these symlinks were not preserved. On Cygwin it works after that; not sure about MinGW.

Comment: what helped was tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz just to repackage it but this time with dereference tar option "-h" tar -cvhzf openssl.tar.gz openssl-1.0.1 and then extract it once again. Stupid but it works. Don't know how to dereference the files while extracting

Answer (score 2):

What program did you use to decompress 'openssl-1.0.0x.tar.gz'? 7-zip is a great program, but it seems there's a bug.

Use tar or other decompressor such as [BreadZip](http://www.bkyang.com/).

> tar zvxf openssl-1.0.0x.tar.gz

It's the same solution as stated above, except it's a bit faster... :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a symbolic link in the archive that MinGW/MSYS does not seem to understand.

You can work around it by using the `--derefence` (`-h`) option when extracting.

For example `tar -xzvfh archive.tar.gz`

from http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/dereference.html:

> When reading from an archive, the `--dereference' (`-h') option causes tar to follow an already-existing symbolic link when tar writes or reads a file named in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.
As the problem is while building the tests, I just did not make them:

```
make Makefile openssl.pc libssl.pc libcrypto.pc build_libs build_apps build_tools
```

Is a horrible solution but it seems to work. You get the libraries and the tools, but not the test suite.

I hope someone gives a better answer and/or fixes the problem with the code if there is any.